# Android: get item position of menu

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer, with some voices.

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
```

One of that voices has id `"list_member"`, in position #2 (so it has id 1).

I need to get that position, to use in another part of code.

Something of this pseudocode:

```
if (navigationView.getMenu().item has label == "list_member") {
id_position = this.getId();
}

navigationView.getMenu().getItem(id_position).setChecked(state);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a tag with [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object)) to your View then iterate over the container of your navigation views and return the child position.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` as like below :

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){


                    case R.id.list_member:

                    // Do your code here...
                        return true;

                    default:

                        return trToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Somethings Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();ue;

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It's same code that I'm using. But, I need the ID position of (for example) R.id.list_member. If this would be at 2nd position, it's id is "1". Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Every `View` has a so called `tag` property, I believe that would suite your need to store such info which would act as "label" in your context.

Details here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:tag

You can set this property either in the layout resource XML or programmatically by calling `view.setTag(Object tag)` or `setTag(int key, Object tag)` and then retreive it by calling `view.getTag()` or `view.getTag(int key)`.

Or you can also call `view.findViewWithTag(Object tag)` on parent view to find a view with a specific tag in it's child views
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object))
in you case it would like something like this:

```
((Checkable) navigationView.getMenu().findViewWithTag("list_member")).setChecked(state);
```

hope this helps